# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "'MONTH'"; SQL statement:

Tags: java, sql, h2

An error occurs when I try to insert into a database with a Prepared Statement. Im Trying to add to the current date to create a new expiration date using the DateAdd function in my H2 Embedded Database.

```
        PreparedStatement sql = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BLOOMHEALTH.CLIENTS VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,DATEADD(?,?,?),?,?,?)");
        String mem = bloomClient.getSsMember();
        try {
            sql.setString(1,bloomClient.getFirstName());
            sql.setString(2,bloomClient.getLastName());
            sql.setString(3,bloomClient.getPhoneNumber());
            sql.setString(4,bloomClient.getBirthday());
            sql.setString(5,bloomClient.getStartDate());
            sql.setString(6,text);
            sql.setInt(7,num);
            sql.setString(8,systemDate());
            sql.setInt(9,bloomClient.getSessionAmount());
            sql.setString(10,bloomClient.getTrainer());
            sql.setString(11,bloomClient.getSsMember());// problem here aswell, says invalid parameter(unsure why)
            sql.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Exact exception is :

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting
> "'MONTH'"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO BLOOMHEALTH.CLIENTS VALUES (
> ?,?,?,?,?,DATEADD(?,?,?),?,?,?) -- (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, DATEADD('',
> ?6, ?7), ?8, ?9, ?10) [22018-200]

Heres what is sent for the data for the SQL statement.

```
        weeks.setText("'WEEK'");
        months.setText("'MONTH'");
```

Comment: can be extra ' you are including in your text as param passing ? tery "WEEK" for example

Comment: Months might have to need to be a valid month name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent releases of H2 don't support parametrization of datetime units in this function any more because it caused other issues. Unfortunately, H2 1.4.200 throws a weird exception instead of actual one, this issue was fixed after that release.

You need to specify a datetime unit directly (`DATEADD(MONTH, ?, ?)`). If you need to support multiple units, you can use a case:

```
INSERT INTO BLOOMHEALTH.CLIENTS VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5,
CASE ?6
    WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, ?7, ?8)
    WHEN 'WEEK' THEN DATEADD(WEEK, ?7, ?8)
    -- put all additional units here
END
?9, ?10, ?11)
```

You also need to use `setText("MONTH")` instead of `"'MONTH'")` (or you can use `'MONTH'` in the case with `WHEN '''MONTH''' THEN …`).